# Error when using Poco Library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, poco-libraries

I'm trying to setup Poco in visual studio 2017 but I get some errors I hope you can help me with..

The thing is, when I try run some of the sample codes from the library, it works fine, but when I try to implement it to my own project it gives me errors like this

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAStartup@8 referenced in function "void __cdecl Poco::Net::initializeNetwork(void)" (?initializeNetwork@Net@Poco@@YAXXZ)    encryption  C:\Users\PATH\encryption\PocoNetmtd.lib(Net.obj)    1

In project properties I have included the include folders from; Net, Foundation, XML and Util.
I have set the system path to the bin folder.
And in project properties I have also added the lib folder to linker.

**Edit 1**

Thanks to rafix07 for finding the first error

Adding Ws2_32.lib fixed a lot of the errors with only one left

> It worked with the most errors! now I'm left with 1 error Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _GetAdaptersInfo@8 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Poco::EnvironmentImpl::nodeIdImpl(unsigned char (&)[6])" (?nodeIdImpl@EnvironmentImpl@Poco@@SAXAAY05E@Z)  VSU_DEB_Simulation  C:\Users\PATH\PocoFoundationmtd.lib(Environment.obj)    1

Comment: It seems `Ws2_32.lib` library is missing, add it in linker options.

Comment: @rafix07 I've edited the description, can you help with this too? :)

Comment: Add this option `-liphlpapi` (*iphlpapi.lib*) and answer whether it helped.

Comment: Perfect, it's working!! Thank you @rafix07

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution to my own question**

Fixed by rafix07!!

First I missed the linking to `Ws2_32.lib` which fixed all the errors except 1..

The only error left was fixed by adding `iphlpapi.lib` to the linker..